# site url is not working after migration in wordpress, all links are broken

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I migrated a WordPress website on my sub directory and change both site_url from wp_options table.Flush the permalink as well but still links are broken.
It seems that site_url() is not working.

Comment: Share your website URL

Comment: @DevKiran, why should he share his URL? it's not relevant. He should add more information though.

Comment: @yivi can't find the issue using the above details. If site URL is available we can fix the issue easily.

Comment: No, you can't. If you need the URL to fix the problem, you are doing it wrong. What you need is a proper [MCVE].

Comment: guys, get_template_directory_uri() mehod not reurn template path, It is the main reason.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a back up of files and database then after open you mysql in code editor, then do search and replace from old links to the new links. Save it and upload the updated sql file to your new database.Now go to backend and save the permalinks.

Answer (score 0):

Please Replace old url to new url in your database

1. UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
2. UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://olddomain.com','http://newdomain.com');
3. UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com');
4. UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value, 'http://olddomain.com', 'http://newdomain.com');